# How to generate app files with Cordova and Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have installed [Visual Studio 2015 with Cordova](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/cordova-vs.aspx) and I have created a very basic Hello World in HTML, JS and CSS! Now I want to generate an Android `.apk` and a Windows Phone `.appx`.

When I use `Build` command, it does not generate those under `platforms\...`. How to generate those appfiles?

#### Configuration

Is it possible I need to configure something somewhere? In `config.xml` I specified all required information about my app (name, version, etc)

#### Note

There are a few questions related to this, however they all refer to an older version of Visual Studio.

Comment: At least it should work...Did you use `cordova build <platform>`??

Comment: Did not know it installed command line tools... i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build with Visual Studio they will be placed in $projectdir\bin\Android\Debug or $projectdir\bin\Android\Release.

Also, make sure you have Device selected as the target.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... but that is my problem. I do not have this Device target...

Comment: Oh... It just appeared now... Damn I am sure it was not there before.

Comment: Can you double check in the tool bar where you select Debug or release from the drop down, Android should be the next drop down, and then the next one should have "Device" in the list along with the various emulators.